# $\vert f(z) \vert \leq M \vert g(z) \vert $ for all $z \in \mathbb{C} $ so that $f(z) = ag(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C} $

Tags: complex-analysis

As in the Titel "$ \vert f(z) \vert \leq M \vert g(z) \vert $ for all $z \in \mathbb{C} $ so that  $f(z) = ag(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C} $ and $a \in \mathbb{C}$."

Now I had the idea to work with the Liouville's Theorem:

$\frac{\vert f(z) \vert}{\vert g(z) \vert} \leq M $ for $g(z) \neq 0 $ and this implies that $\frac{\vert f(z) \vert}{\vert g(z) \vert}$ is a constant right? and therefore $a := \frac{\vert f(z) \vert}{\vert g(z) \vert}$ and we are done for the case $g(z) \neq 0 $ (if it is right?).

Now I struggle with the argumentation that this holds also for $g(z) = 0 $ what am I missing?

Thank you guys !

Comment: You can remove singularities by the Riemann singularity removal theorem, since $f(z)/g(z)$ remains bounded.

Comment: If $g=0$,you're done. Otherwise, the set of zeros is isolated (perhaps empty) and you can perform the division to get a meromorphic function. However the function you get is bounded, so by Riemann's singularity theorem, the quotient $f/g$ muat extend holomorphically to all of $\Bbb{C}$. Now you can use Loiville.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct for $z\neq 0$. Now let $z$ be s.t $g(z)=0$. Since $|f(z)|\leq M|g(z)|$, $f(z)=0$. Since $g,f$ are entire, their zeroes are isolated, so we can take $\mathbb{D}_r(z)$ s.t for every $\omega\in\mathbb{D}_r(z)$, $g(\omega),f(\omega)\neq 0$. I'll show that $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}_r(z)$. But by the assumption, $|\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}|\leq M$, so by Riemann's singularity removal theorem, $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}_r(z)$. Since this is true for every $z$ s.t $g(z)=0$, and you've already showed that $\frac{f}{g}$ is holomorphic for every $z$ s.t $g(z)\neq 0$, we have that $\frac{f}{g}$ is entire. By Liouville's theorem, $\frac{f}{g}=a$ and therefore $f(z)=ag(z)$. (This is of course assuming $g\not\equiv 0$)